# Prefer A (IPv4) DNS lookups before AAAA(IPv6) lookups

Tags: dns

In notice my newly installed Ubuntu 10.10 always does an AAAA DNS lookup before A record lookups. Is there any way I can configure the system to do A lookups first ?

(While various browsers and other applications might contain their own resolvers, i'm talking about the ones in glibc)

Comment: To clarify, you do want to have both IPv4 and IPv6 present?

Comment: Preferrably yes. But as I only have link local IPv6, it\s quite a waste asking for e.g. the AAAA record of google.com every time, and then ask for the A record afterwards.

Answer (score 80):

It's the standard to prioritize IPv6 over IPv4 to allow next-generation IP take over :)

You can change this by editing the precedence blocks in `/etc/gai.conf` (gai stands for `getaddrinfo`, the standard system call for resolving host names). Just comment out the line as described in the file:

> #  For sites which prefer IPv4 connections change the last line to
>
> #precedence ::ffff:0:0/96  100

A detailed explanation on `gai.conf` can be found in the [man gai.conf(5)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/gai.conf.5.html).

Comment: thanks, u saved my day! one of my server keeps getting ipv6 results from the dns server but my server just couldn't work properly w/ ipv6

Comment: Hi, does this setting require a sysctl or any service reload or a reboot to take effect? I found your answer useful, but you might edit it in order to fix such doubts.

Comment: The man page for `gai.conf` says you have to un-comment *all* the lines, not just the IPv4 one, to get the correct modified behaviour.  From `gai.conf(5)`:  "Once again, the presence of a single precedence line in the configuration file causes the default table to not be used."  If you want the other default table lines to keep working, you have to un-comment them as well.

Answer (score 18):

My problem was the same, i had IPv6 queries made before IPv4 and they where wasting resources, so I did changed my `/etc/gai.conf` file as freddyb posted, but my scenario is a little bit different, my server is Natted, so IPv4 will not have precedence over IPv6 with only that line. The solution is also commenting out others lines at `/etc/gai.conf` so it will look like this

```
# For sites which prefer IPv4 connections change the last line to
precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
...
#    For sites which use site-local IPv4 addresses behind NAT there is
#    the problem that even if IPv4 addresses are preferred they do not
#    have the same scope and are therefore not sorted first.  To change
#    this use only these rules:
#
scopev4 ::ffff:169.254.0.0/112  2
scopev4 ::ffff:127.0.0.0/104    2
scopev4 ::ffff:0.0.0.0/96       14
```

So your server will try first ipv4 even if you are Natted!

Comment: The `/etc/gai.conf` file in Ubuntu 15.04 "vivid" says those three `scopev4` lines you suggest above are already the default.  I made only the one-line `precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100` change and that worked even behind NAT.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want IPv6 enabled at all, you can disable IPv6 to accomplish this.
http://www.webupd8.org/2010/05/how-to-disable-ipv6-in-ubuntu-1004.html

if not, you can try addding

```
options single-request
```

To your /etc/resolv.conf file.  (see http://udrepper.livejournal.com/20948.html for gory details)

Comment: The manual page for resolv.conf indicates that the option you suggest does exactly the oposite "This option [...] makes glibc perform the IPv6 and IPv4 requests sequentially (at the cost of some slowdown of the resolving process)." -- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/resolver.5.html

Comment: sequential = first one, then the other - as opposed to parallel. it works fine here.