# How do I upgrade Ubuntu in WSL? Getting some kind of connection error

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 17.10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have had terrible luck trying to upgrade Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (xenial) to 17.10 (artful) in Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL). Here is an example of my best attempt:

Starting from a fresh install of [Ubuntu](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6) on Windows 10 Pro (build 16299.248), I did the following:

```
$ sudo vim /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades  # set Prompt=normal
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt install update-manager-core
$ sudo env RELEASE_UPGRADER_NO_SCREEN=1 do-release-upgrade
```

The full output is [here](https://gist.github.com/jacktose/35ee3d7a26ebe283a7275c092d69723e), but this is the error I got:

```
0% [Connecting to archive.ubuntu.com]
http: ../sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c:2603: getaddrinfo: Assertion `IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED (sin6->sin6_addr.s6_addr32)' failed.
```

I get the same error sometimes when running `sudo apt update`:

```
$ sudo apt update
0% [Working]http: ../sysdeps/posix/getaddrinfo.c:2603: getaddrinfo: Assertion `IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED (sin6->sin6_addr.s6_addr32)' failed.
Reading package lists... Done
E: Method http has died unexpectedly!
E: Sub-process http received signal 6.
$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
388 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
```

But it's intermittent, apparently random. I can re-run `sudo apt update` until it works, but it seems that `do-release-upgrade` is too long and complicated. Sometimes it goes farther than others, but it always dies at some point, with that `getaddrinfo` error (and a lot of stack barf).

(Also note that *something* has changed after the upgrade attempt, because `apt` is looking at `artful` stuff now.)

I have [tried](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/614) a [lot](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2142) of [advice](https://askubuntu.com/q/958876/582404) on the topic with no improvement. (Notably, I seem unable to disable IPv6.) But there are not so many answers that I think everyone is having this problem.
Is this upgrade even possible? And how?

Comment: The IN6_IS_ADDR_V4MAPPED issue should be fixed in the spring 2018 update of WSL. Has something to do with "TDI filters" that can be altered by 3rd party windows applications, don't know more than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @bengt-olsson points out above, this should be fixed in the 2018 spring release, arriving "soon" :)

Also note: Upgrading a Linux distro beyond the latest version offered in the Windows Store may result in failures because the newer code may use syscalls that the WSL team have not yet implemented.

If you want a stable experience, we recommend you NOT upgrade beyond the supported distro version published in the Windows Store. We work with the distro vendors to help test and certify new distro releases, and the vendors will upgrade their distros when ready.

Comment: Hey @rich-turner, any update on this or any official guide to do this in recommended way?

Comment: @AbhiNickz Sorry for the delay - I assume you're running Win10 Spring 2018 Update? If so, this issue should now be fixed. In fact, you could even install [Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-1804/9n9tngvndl3q) for WSL directly from the store if you prefer!