# Ubuntu on wsl always "fails to fetch" whenever I'm trying to download to it. How can i fix this?

Tags: updates, dns, windows-subsystem-for-linux, gcc

I'm just starting out on Linux (working on WSL since it's probably the simplest option for me), as I'm trying to run the Community Multiscale Air Quality modeling system. This requires a compiler, but for some reason, I can't get Ubuntu to download anything. For example, when I tried to update Ubuntu, i get this:

[image: failed to fetch]

A similar thing happens when I try to download the gcc compiler.

[image]

[image]

I've already tried changing my DNS settings (nameserver 1.1.1.1 and 8.8.8.8) and apt-get clean, to no results. Also, I can ping google no problem, so I don't think it is a problem with my internet connection.

I also checked if Linux was downloading from a mirror, but it appears to be using the main page.

[image: but it appears to be using the main page]

This is literally my first time ever using Linux so anything helps! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use [code block]s for formatting them.

Comment: I'd try disabling IPv6 - see for example [How to disable IPv6 on Windows Subsystem for Linux?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958876/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-windows-subsystem-for-linux)